# JQuery UI Link to a Tab with AjaxContent

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I´m using JQueryUI with 2 Tabs (a normal and an ajax one) as follow:

```
<div class="g12 tab">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tab-general">GENERAL</a></li>
        <li><a href="/CONTENT/AJAX/">EXTERNAL</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tab-general">CONTENT HERE</div>
</div>
```

When I need to open the first tab from a external page I just put #tab-general (www.mydomain.com/Page#tab-general) and it works fine.

How can I open the ajax tab from a direct link?

Comment: why you kept /CONTENT/AJAX/

Comment: are you using .tabs() in jQuery

Comment: Hello @PSR, I´m loading content for the second tab from this page "Content/AJAX/". Yes, I´m using .tabs().

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery .tabs() then try the following when you came from ajax

```
$('#selectorId').tabs({ selected: 2});
```

Comment: @Slobodonosor try this once after loading

Comment: Hi, I´m not coming from ajax. I´m just loading ajax content in the second tab. Thank you.

Comment: try this after loading ajax content $('#selectorId').tabs({ selected: 2})